# Mongodb prevent empty values while updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of words, the scheme is as follows:

```
var wordsSchema = new Schema({

    name         : { type : String  , trim : true , required : true , unique : true , index: true},
    definition   : { type : String  , trim : true , required : true }

});
```

when I try to save new word with empty name or definition into collection `required: true`  works end return error,but when I try to update collection and set empty name or definition value `required:true` doesn't works and updated word with empty fields saves into collection I want to prevent saving empty words into collection. How can I achieve this with a shortest way, My Update code looks like this:

```
words.update({ _id : word._id }, { $set : {

            name       : word.name,
            definition : word.definition
        } 

    } , function(err,data) {

        if(err) {
            res.status(1033).send("There was error while changing word");
        } else {
            res.send('Word has successfully changed');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`required:true` is not something maintained at the database level, but rather mongoose itself handles that for you. when you do an update operation, mongoose *doesn't* run your validators (`required:true` is a type of validator).

There is a change coming up in mongoose 4 where validators get run on updates. For now, your options are

- manually check if there's nothing there (enforced by your application)
- do a find on the document, then edit the field and do `doc.save` which will run validators (enforced by mongoose)
- add a document with an empty value for 'word'. because you have a `unique` index on that field, mongodb will not allow you to insert another document without a value for that field (enforced by mongodb)

I would recommend that last option.